# java or smart gwt- authentication for a REST data source with OAuth

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I want to create a Java based REST API and secure it using OAuth.

Are there any recommended how tos or best practices for accomplishing this?

Another question- I want to bind smart GWT components to the REST data source, and I am confused about authentication- how do I ensure that only a user who is logged in, will be able to update/delete/create/insert data using the REST data source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many other ways, but I use Spring and [Spring Security](http://www.springsource.org/spring-security).  It has lots of different security filters to secure your REST APIs which includes [OAuth](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/oauth/).  The social libraries include a lot of controllers (part of MVC) that are useful "out of the box" OAuth with other sites.

Getting started with Spring Security is easy and should just involve: modifications to the web.xml (adding a "springSecurityFilterChain"), designing a security context with rules and an OAuth security filter.  So, searching for something like "Spring Security Tutorial" will walk you through ways to do this.